# Read Non-Delimited .txt file into R

Tags: r, import

I was given a dataset of binary data indicating right/wrong test answers for a fictitious test.  I am to import this data into R to perform analyses on it for a course.

I am having difficulty importing the dataset into R without R changing the values in each row into a single, large number.  My initial belief is that the lack of delimiting characters is causing me issues.

The first few lines of the .txt file appear below:

> 11011111110001100000001110000010
>
> 11111100110000001010001000100000
>
> 00001011110000000000000010001000
>
> 11110101000101100111000100000110
>
> 10000000100000100101000000101000
>
> 11111110001000001001000010000000

When I read these lines into R, I receive:

> 1.101111e+31
>
> 1.111110e+31
>
> 1.011110e+27
>
> 1.111010e+31
>
> 1.000000e+31
>
> 1.111111e+31

Rather than the lines of 1s and 0s indicating test results.

Comment: How are you importing the data? readLines() usually works for me, maintaining the input as character instead of converting to numeric.

Comment: I had been using the read.table which, I believe was causing the issue in converting the rows into single values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that your data is character. `R` is being clever and taking it to be a number. Use `colClasses` in `read.table`...

```
read.table( text = "11011111110001100000001110000010
11111100110000001010001000100000
00001011110000000000000010001000
11110101000101100111000100000110
10000000100000100101000000101000
11111110001000001001000010000000" , colClasses = "character" , h = FALSE )

#                                V1
#1 11011111110001100000001110000010
#2 11111100110000001010001000100000
#3 00001011110000000000000010001000
#4 11110101000101100111000100000110
#5 10000000100000100101000000101000
#6 11111110001000001001000010000000
```

Comment: Excellent - the majority of my issue seemed to stem from looking for a way to separate the columns rather than treating the values as characters.

Comment: If you want to easily split the characters after reading in you can use... `do.call( rbind , sapply( df , strsplit , "" ) )` assuming your `data.frame` is called `df`. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing that each row is an observation? For example, each row contains the correctness of a student's 32 answers. If that's the case, try `read.fwf`:

```
my.data <- "11011111110001100000001110000010
11111100110000001010001000100000
00001011110000000000000010001000
11110101000101100111000100000110
10000000100000100101000000101000
11111110001000001001000010000000"

test.results <- read.fwf(textConnection(my.data), widths=rep(1, 32))

test.results[1, ]
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24
# 1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
# V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32
# 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

If that's not the case, you should provide some more information.

Comment: read.fwf looks like it will be extremely helpful for some other data I have - thank you for sharing this technique.

Comment: @SimonO101, yeah, it's in the dusty back corner of the toolbox, though I know there are some larger or older datasets that like fixed-width formats. Give me delimiters or give me death!